# Rails 7 encryption configuration not correctly set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to migrate a project from `attr_encrypted` to Rails 7 encryption. The testing that I am doing right now is only on the development & test environments, so migrating data is not necessary for now.

The steps that I did were:

1. changing everything from `attr_encrypted` syntax to `encrypts`
2. running `bin/rails db:encryption:init` and adding these values into the development & test credentials
   2.1. I also tried using `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:encryption:init` and putting those into the test credentials, in case the different dbs needed different values

The issue that I am having right now is that whenever I run the tests (which start with a clean db) I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Configuration:
        key_derivation_salt is not configured. Please configure it via credential active_record_encryption.key_derivation_salt or by setting config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt
```

Although if I go into Rails console I do get the values:

```
 Credentials[:active_record_encryption]
=> {:primary_key=>"T..", :deterministic_key=>"k..", :key_derivation_salt=>"6.."}
```

In a desperate attempt to fix this issue or at least see what helps, I added to the environments Ruby files these lines:

```
config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = Credentials[:active_record_encryption][:key_derivation_salt]
  config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = Credentials[:active_record_encryption][:primary_key]
  config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = Credentials[:active_record_encryption][:deterministic_key]
```

This seems to fix the error, **but** the tests fail because it seems like it is decrypting the values as `nil` (tests were previously passing ofc)

Am I missing a configuration step?

I think that these null values come from not updating them inside the database? How would I do that?

Also, is there any other way so I do not need to add these lines into the environment files? It seems kind of redundant.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I did not unfortunately

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, when i run `$rails c -e test` and grab the credentials via `Rails.application.config.active_record` it shows the credentials loading in the test environment but the test still fail with `ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption: ActiveRecord::Encryption::Errors::Decryption`

Answer (score 16):

First run this command

```
bin/rails db:encryption:init
```

This will generate the following

```
Add this entry to the credentials of the target environment: 

active_record_encryption:
  primary_key: Q3TJUKuOUGSZmgqaD2WZ72pQdg5Rikfn
  deterministic_key: lYew1Q7BE98tDXdqytP3iwvJcu8dYulX
  key_derivation_salt: 9REysw2kZuLybtKjtJsIZHg8cTd2DyMT
```

Add the following config in **application.rb**

```
config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = ENV['ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_PRIMARY_KEY']
config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = ENV['ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_DETERMINISTIC_KEY']
config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = ENV['ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_KEY_DERIVATION_SALT']
```

You can either add this **config/credentials/local.yml.enc**

Then you can configure this by following.

```
config.credentials.content_path = 'config/credentials/local.yml.enc'
```

OR

```
config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:primary_key]
config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:deterministic_key]
config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:key_derivation_salt]
```

**Ref Link:**
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html

https://www.freshworks.com/eng-blogs/managing-rails-application-secrets-with-encrypted-credentials-blog/

Comment: This fails for me. In http://localhost:3000/admin/action_text~encrypted_rich_text I get:
    uncompress_if_needed(cipher.decrypt(message, key: keys.collect(&:secret), **cipher_options), message.headers.compressed)
      rescue *(ENCODING_ERRORS + DECRYPT_ERRORS)
        raise Errors::Decryption
      end

      # Returns whether the text is encrypted or not

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I wanted to read the encryption keys from environment variables using an initializer rather than using Rails credentials, and I was running into this error.

It turns out there's an ActiveRecord initializer that runs *before* anything in `config/initializers` that reads the keys and saves them, so if you edit `Rails.application.credentials` or `Rails.application.config.active_record.encryption` later, the keys ActiveRecord sees will be `nil`.

This fixed the problem for me:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Encryption.configure(
  primary_key: ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_PRIMARY_KEY"],
  deterministic_key: ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_DETERMINISTIC_KEY"],
  key_derivation_salt: ENV["ACTIVE_RECORD_ENCRYPTION_KEY_DERIVATION_SALT"]
)
```

I found `ActiveRecord::Encryption.configure` by reading the code but it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so be careful in case it changes.

Answer (score 1):

im not expert but this work for me just update the application.rb

```
config.active_record.encryption.primary_key = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:primary_key]
config.active_record.encryption.deterministic_key = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:deterministic_key]
config.active_record.encryption.key_derivation_salt = Rails.application.credentials[:active_record_encryption][:key_derivation_salt]
```

Comment: I did end up adding `config.active_record.encryption = Credentials[:active_record_encryption]` in each environment file. I think it might work the same for adding these in `application.rb`

Comment: @VictorMotogna you can have it in the application.rb file if you just do `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:active_record_encryption][:primary_key]`

Answer (score 1):

for **LockBox** gem users:

if you encountered this issue when upgrading to Rails 7 and you already use LockBox then beware:

> The new native Rails encryption implementation also uses `encrypts` in model class. This might be conflicting with your LockBox implementation.

To fix this issue you can simply

1. upgrade the Lockbox gem version to

`v0.6.4` or greater, and

2. change the

`encrypts`

to

`lockbox_encrypts`

in the model class. That is it.

You can find the related GitHub discussion [here](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/issues/107).

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually added the attribute that was originally provided by `attr_encrypted` to the model through a migration?

Because the gem stored the old values in `fieldname_encrypted` and `fieldname_encrypted_iv` and the table does not contain `fieldname`, hence the decrypted value is returned as nil.

In my case the migration looked like this:

```
  def change
    add_column :tenants, :smtp_password, :string
    remove_column :tenants, :encrypted_smtp_password, :string
    remove_column :tenants, :encrypted_smtp_password_iv, :string
  end
```

EDIT:
Have you stored the result from `bin/rails db:encryption:init`  underneath the enviroment's entry in the credentials file? I.e:

```
development:
  active_record_encryption:
    primary_key: foo
    deterministic_key: bar
    key_derivation_salt: baz
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing, removing the `encrypted_field` & `encrypted_field_iv`, and adding `field`, but the problem still persists unfortunately